# Google search API wrapper for Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-search-api

I am looking for a Google search API wrapper to be used in Node.js, I have searched around but haven't found something updated and fully baked. Can anyone please recommend something working?
Thanks

Comment: Use https://www.serphouse.com to search on Google via API and get data in JSON structure

Answer (score 7):

Why aren't you using node client lib for Google APIs? https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client

```
var googleapis = require('googleapis');
googleapis.discover('customsearch', 'v1').execute(function(err, client) {
  // set api key
  client.withApiKey('...');
  client.search.cse.list({ q: '...' }).execute(console.log);
});
```

Comment: I don't see any documentation that cse is supported by google's node wrapper. Is it?

Comment: To specify a custom search engine, specify a `cx` property in the config object, next to the `q` property. A full example is available in the GitHub repo : https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/examples/customsearch.js

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are not referring to the deprecated Google Web Search API...

The [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) is a RESTful API.  This means that you can easily access it without a specialized wrapper.

There are a couple of modules that make this easier.  The one I usually use is the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module, which lets you make HTTP requests very simply.

Answer (score 3):

I just used node-google-images and it worked right away in less than 2 minutes:

https://github.com/vdemedes/node-google-images

Just call

```
npm install google-images
```

and then

```
client = require( 'google-images' );

client.search( 'Chicken Teriyaki', function (err, images) {
    console.log(images)
});
```

will return

> [ { width: '1920',
>       height: '1280',
>       url: 'http://www.springkitchenrestaurant.com/Chicken_Teriyaki.jpg',
>       writeTo: [Function] }]

(actually, it will return 4 results but stackoverflow prevents me from posting more than 2 links... - you get the gist!)

Comment: It is giving only one image data, How can I get more than 10 using this? Or I want an array of image data. Can you plz help me how can get an array of images of the search keyword.

Comment: I think it was depreciated a while back. I use yahoo image search now. It costs a little but works decently.
https://yboss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/images

Answer (score 1):

You can use jsearch module. Install with:

```
npm install jsearch
```

Usage:

```
js.google('queryStringYouWant',10,function(response){
    console.log(response) // for Google results 
})
```

Comment: What is the 10?
is it a number of urls what I get? I think it is not giving the relevant URL what I want to search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third-party service like [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com) with its [Node.js library](https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-nodejs) to scrape Google and get back structured JSON.

To install it:

```
npm install google-search-results-nodejs
```

Code example:

```
var gsr = require('GoogleSearchResults')
let serp = new gsr.GoogleSearchResults()
query_params = {
  q: "query",
  google_domain: "Google Domain", 
  location: "Location Requested", 
  device: device,
  hl: "Google UI Language",
  gl: "Google Country",
  safe: "Safe Search Flag",
  num: "Number of Results",
  start: "Pagination Offset",
  serp_api_key: "demo"
}

callback = function(data) {
 console.log(data)
}

// Show result as JSON
serp.json(query_params, callback)

// Show results as JSON with Images
serp.jsonWithImages(query_params, callback)

// Show result as HTML file
serp.html(query_params, callback)
```